# CSS Border too high, height doesnt affect element

Tags: html, css

I have a rather simple HTML construction. Now the border of this element is too high, I have read already that I can change it only by changing the height of the element. But tweaking the height doesnt change anything. There must be a rather simple solution. Thank you for your help.

```css
.carFilter{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.boxyc{
    padding:20px;
      border-top:1px solid white;
      border-bottom:1px solid white;
      border-left:1px solid white;
      border-right:1px solid white;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    color:#999999;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:150%;
    margin:0;
}

.boxycx{
    padding:20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:20%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="carFilter">
 <p class="boxycx">Bla Bla:</p>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"> <p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"> <p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: The border is set in the span. Neither changing height of p or span does change the height of the border,

Comment: If you see my snippet I have increased the border from `1px` to `10px`, is that what you need? or what exactly you need from the snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Give some `margin:0;` to the `p` class.

```css
.carFilter {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: teal;
  padding: 10px;
}

.boxyc {
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  border-bottom: 10px solid white;
  border-left: 10px solid white;
  border-right: 10px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: red;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 10px;
}

.vcxvcx {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="carFilter">
  <p class="boxycx">Bla Bla:</p>
  <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
  <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"> <p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
  <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
  <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"> <p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
  <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
</div>
```

Comment: I just want the gray stuff to be "shorter". Do you know if thsts possible ? So it cuts just above/  below the text.

Comment: @Bitlord check and let me know if this is what you need?

Answer (score 1):

The padding (and flexbox) is setting the height. I changed the padding for boxyc to 5px 20px. Adjust to suit your needs.

```css
.carFilter{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}

.boxyc{
    padding:5px 20px;
      border-top:1px solid white;
      border-bottom:1px solid white;
      border-left:1px solid white;
      border-right:1px solid white;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:#CCCCCC;
    color:#999999;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size:150%;
    margin:0;
}

.boxycx{
    padding:20px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height:20%;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="carFilter">
 <p class="boxycx">Bla Bla:</p>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"> <p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"> <p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 <span id="boxyc" class="boxyc"><p class="vcxvcx">bla</p></span>
 </div>
```

Comment: I have already solved it by adding a margin:0 to the p elements. But thank you anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Add margin:0 to the p elements solves the too large border/background.